# Comparing Google Maps v2 Screenshot in Android Test

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, integration-testing

I would like to compare 2 Google Maps v2 screenshots in Android test. Is there any advice where should I start?

I've already used https://facebook.github.io/screenshot-tests-for-android/, but it still can't capture Google Maps v2 (because the map is rendered on OpenGL).

My idea: Create a gradle task to take a snapshot of Google Maps v2 using SnapshotReadyCallback, and then compare it using OpenCV. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you take a snapshot with Maps v2 :

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                Bitmap bitmap;

                @Override
                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                    bitmap = snapshot;
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Download/globe.png");
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // OR
                    ImageView im1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImView);
                    im1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            };

            map.snapshot(callback);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've implemented your solution before, it worked, but I'm intending to use the screenshot on Instrumentation Test, and compare it with another screenshot in my local computer disk.